# How to serve a subdomain and the domain on a single django-cms?

Tags: django, django-cms, django-wsgi

Is is possible to serve a subdomain and the main domain on the same django-cms instance ?

For example: how to serve the following submains and the main domain on the same Django-CMS instance ?

```
   abc.mydomain.com
   xyz.mydomain.com
   www.mydomain.com
```

If so, what are needed to be done in Apache httpd.conf and Django-CMS ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Marco Thank you. It seems that the link you provided does provide solutions to my question. In that question, people  suggested option A: Rewrite subdomain to subdirectory, Option B: use Django-subdomains, Option C: use Django-hosts. I guess that any of those will work. Since that article was 6 years old, just wonder which will be best solutions today ? which one will you recommend ?

Answer (score 1):

> What needs to be done with Apache httpd.conf?

```
<virtualhost *:80>
  ServerName one.example.com
....
</virtualhost>
```

```
<virtualhost *:80>
  ServerName two.example.com
....
</virtualhost>
```

ServerName within the Apache config is what's used to identify and run name-based hosts. You can read more about that [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/name-based.html)

In regards to the Django-CMS, you'd need to read their documentation as they have a specific setup [for hosting multiple sites.](https://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/how_to/multi-site.html)